# Delete empty elements in vector and create vector with only data

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, vector

I have a vector that has empty elements and then some pieces of data in it that I can't predict the index of. I just want to delete all the empty elements and leave a vector with only the data. I can't just try to pull the indices with data because the amount of data can vary and show up at different indices (I'm extracting from a pdf).

I've tried to make a for loop that will check if an element isn't empty and then store it in a separate vector:

```
n <- 1
for (i in withspace) {
  if (withspace[[1]][i] != "") {
    wospace[n] <- withspace[[1]][i]
    n <- n + 1
  }
}
```

But I keep getting an error like this:

```
Error in if (withspace[[1]][i] != "") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In if (withspace[[1]][i] != "") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

withspace is the matrix storing all the data points and wospace is an initialized empty vector. This is what withspace looks like:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "City"      ""          ""          ""          ""          ""         
 [7] ""          ""          ""          ""          ""          ""         
[13] ""          ""          ""          ""          ""          ""         
[19] ""          " Province" ""          ""          ""          ""         
[25] ""          ""          ""          ""          ""          ""         
[31] ""          ""          ""          " Postal"
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: R is vectorized so no need for a loop here.  Something like this should work for you: `withspace[[1]][withspace[[1]] != ""]`

Comment: Also, it should be `for(i in withspace[[1]])`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I've been pulling my hair out for hours and now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Dave2e:

```
withspace[[1]][withspace[[1]] != ""]
```

should do the trick.

A few more observations:

1. Your loop cycles through the vector elements of `withspace[[1]]` but within the loop you treat it as index. If you want an index, you need to define the loop as `for (i in 1:length(withspace[[1]]))`.
2. `whithspace` is clearly a list or data frame. The vector of interest, however, is `withspace[[1]]`. But in your loop, you loop through the top-level (list) elements. You have to set the loop as `for (i in withspace[[1]])`. In this case, `withspace[[1]][i]` does not make sense inside the loop. You have to address `i` directly which is an copy of the according element of `withspace[[1]]`.

Comment: instead of extracting twice,may be `v1 <- withspace[[1]]; v1[v1 != '']` would reduce the repetition

Comment: Yes I did withspace[[1]][withspace[[1]] != ""] and it worked. I'm not familiar with R and am more used to having to use for loops to iterate through every vector so this was super helpful information. I'm doing something similar again and your observations are exactly what I need so thank you!